# Mostrar os dados de um array 2d em ReactNative

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, atom

Eu tenho este array, e queria mostrar os dados contidos dentro dele como faço?

```
var questions = [["test ss aa","test asdd as"],["test  a","test asxc  a"],["test xs aws","test scaca"]]
```

Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let result = function() {
    let hist = {};

    return arr.reduce(function(previous, current) {
        if (current in hist) {
            previous[hist[current]][2]++;
        } else {
            previous[hist[current] = previous.length] = current.concat(1);
        }
        return previous;
    }, []);
}();
```